# Checkbox unchecked state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following function that returns me an array of the checkbox's that are checked.

```
function grabData(checked) {
    return $('.product_category_selector' + (checked? ':checked' : ':not(:checked)')).map(function (index, chk) {
        return $(chk).data('id');
    }).get();
```

In my main processing function I currently have the 'state' hard coded to `1`

What would be the best way to make this dynamic?

**Full Code:**

```
        $('body').on("click", "#brands_by_category_submit_btn", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();               
            var self       = $(this);
            var sortOrder  =  []; 
            var id         = $("#manID").data("id");
            var brand_name = $("#brand_name").data("id");
            var data       = grabData(true);

            $(".order").each(function(){
                sortOrder.push($(this).val());
            })

            if(data.length)
            {
                var data_array = { 
                    id : id,
                    brand_name : brand_name, 
                    cat_id     : data,
                    sortOrder  : sortOrder, 
                    state      : 1
                };
```

Comment: what is the meaning of state?

Comment: What values should be assigned to state in dynamic?

Comment: @Sudhir State is the checked state of the checkbox's 0 and 1

Comment: @RohanKumar State should be 0 or 1 but this depends on whats in data

Comment: Since you are hard coding the checked state in the method.... it is ok.. else you can use a ternary operator like `checked ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:checked` selector to get only those you're interested in, then map those `data-id` attributes to an array.

without `grabData()` call:

```
var $checked = $(":checked");
var data = $.map($checked, function(item){ return item.attr('data-id') });
```

with `grabData()` call:

```
function grabData(){
    var $checked = $(":checked");
    var data = $.map($checked, function(item){ return item.attr('data-id') });

    return data;
}

var data = grabData();
```

Comment: Would that allow me to use the same data array?

Comment: I'm saying you don't even use the `grabData` function. Or if you want, move it into `grabData` and add `return data;` to it.

Comment: I have got the error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLOptionElement> has no method 'attr'

Comment: Can you give me an example of moving it into `grabData`

Comment: On this line ` var data = $.map($checked, function(item){ return item.attr('data-id') });` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLOptionElement> has no method 'attr' `

Comment: `$(item).attr('data-id')` sorry, i didn't test this code first. The parameter is a native object, so you need to convert it to a jQuery object to use `.attr`